# How to intercepts requests using Burp Suite on 3G network

Tags: intercept

Does anybody know how to intercepts requests using 3 G network on Burp Suite. Right now we are

intercepting requesting using wifi. But one of my client ask this question, is it possible to

intercepts requests using 3G sim.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Winpcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) to intercept data on any connection.